# Ruby has no constant values?

Tags: ruby, constants

It's possible to write this way

```
class Foo
 MY_CONST = 100
end
```

and it's also possible to change it `Foo::MY_CONST = 123`

There will be a warning from a Ruby compiler, but anyway a constant will be changed.

So Ruby has no constant values?

Comment: Indirectly related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441524/closest-ruby-representation-of-a-private-static-final-and-public-static-final#2442640

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1977780/38765

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it depends what kind of action you want to do with your constants.

If you have an

```
ARRAY = [1,2,3]
#and then 
ARRAY << 4
```

Ruby won't complain.

However, if you

```
ARRAY = [1,2,3].freeze
#and
ARRAY << 4
#RuntimeError: can't modify frozen Array
```

You can still

```
ARRAY = [1,2,3,4]
#warning: already initialized constant ARRAY
```

Answer (score 1):

If you `freeze` `FOO`, then trying to reassign `FOO::MY_CONST` will create a RuntimeError.

```
class FOO
  MY_CONST = 100
end

FOO.freeze
FOO::MY_CONST = 123
```

gives

```
RuntimeError: can't modify frozen Class
```

Answer (score 0):

They are semantically constants, so you can expect people not to change them. I'd call them liberal constants, see http://pastie.org/4608297

Comment: They can be changed. Even if people might not want to change them.