# Why reference to variable inside not run if body does not raise NoMethodError?

Tags: ruby

Hi I got a variable inside an if block that the condition of if is false.

```rb
if false
  a = 1
end

a => nil
```

However the `a` does not raise an `NoMethodError` instead returns `nil`?

Answer (score 1):

### Why `a = 1` Isn't Evaluated

Your code is logically equivalent to both of the following:

- `a = 1 if false; a`
- `false.eql?(true) && a=(1)`

In all three cases, since `false` is not true, variable *a* is never assigned. However, the reason it's `nil` rather than raising NameError is a little non-intuitive.

### Why Unassigned Variables Return `nil` Instead of Raising NameError

In Ruby, non-constant variables are defined when encountered by the parser, rather then when executed by the code path. If the parser encounters a non-constant variable that is not an assignment, it creates the variable and assigns `nil` to it.

You can still expect to see NameError when the interpreter *uses* an unassigned variable. For example, in a fresh irb session:

```
# variable not in scope
puts a
#=> NameError (undefined local variable or method `a' for main:Object)

# variable auto-vivified by parser
a = 1 if false; a
#=> nil

a = 1; a
#=> 1
```

### Related

[Why are constants not initialized like local variables when the file is parsed by Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62302469/why-are-constants-not-initialized-like-local-variables-when-the-file-is-parsed-b)

Comment: @JörgWMittag Thanks for clarifying. Revised to address that.

Answer (score 0):

The Ruby parser keeps track of which names are local variables (vs method calls). Ruby parser doesn’t know if the conditionals will be `true`/`false`, so it already got an reference to `a`.